# Eclipse Mars Glassfish 4.1 - Key value shall not be null

Tags: java, eclipse, glassfish, eclipse-mars

I will integration Glassfish 4.1 on Eclipse Mars. But I received an error when glassfish started.

**"Key value shall not be null."**

I could not find resolition anywhere. But after one day found out resolition. There are a few missing starting parametres on Glassfish and Eclipse.

**Here is the solution :**
Adding that line to domain.xml

**-Duser.language=en**
and that line to eclipse.ini

**-Duser.language=en**
solved the problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, try to delete the default domain (domain1) and add a clean one. Also consider changing the debug port.

I did it and it worked, whereas the solution above did not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

When I started domain with consol , my application run . But I run on server to it in eclipce , it didn't work .
" -Duser.language=en and that line to eclipse.ini " That solved this problem