# Starting GlassFish 4 Error

Tags: glassfish, server, glassfish-4.1

I get that error when I attempt to start the Glassfish server 4 at localhost[domain1]

**Unable to start server due to following issues:
Key value shall not be null.**

[Here's the ScreenShot of it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKHpc.png)

I could not find a solution.

Thank you.

Comment: This might be an issue of eclipse or its plugin for glassfish. Can you have a look into the server log and post something related to this error? You can gind the log either in console window in eclipse, or in file in glassfish installation on path `glassfish/domains/domain1/logs/server.log`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a configuration issue:

As mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34008480/2546444) you have to change two of your config files:

1. In the Glassfish `domain.xml` (located in `glassfish\domains\%domainname%\config`) find the section `<java-config` in the `<config name="server-config">` section and add the following line into it:

   > -Duser.language=en
2. In the `eclipse.ini` (located in your root folder of your eclipse installation) add the following line at the end:

   > -Duser.language=en

Answer (score 0):

This problem may be occured because of GlassFish directory. If your GlassFish folder is in the Program Files directory , you need to run your IDE as administrator. Another way is to move the GlassFish folder to a different directory such as C:\GlassFish.
These solutions worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Eclipse Mars2. I added

```
-Duser.language=en
```

line to eclipse.ini but that wasn't enough.

I also had to run Eclipse as Administrator and Glassfish (4.1) works fine now.

Comment: You have to add it into domain.xml as well.